# WinDbg 64-bit error: Failed to load data access DLL

Tags: windbg

I have received a mini dump file from our network support team. They complain that one of our sites on the production node causes high cpu usage.

The Windows server is x64 but the IIS App Pool is running in `32-bit` mode. The network/support guys have used the default task manager to create the dump file so I assume the dump file must be a 64-bit one.

I downloaded WinDbg x64. Then I tried to follow the instruction given in the link below to find which part of the code can be problematic:

[site](http://raghurana.com/blog/?p=144)

Although the dump file and WinDbg both are 64-bit, when I run "lmvm clr"command, the debugger shows this line:

Image path: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll`

If I run this command:

`.loadby sos clr`

and then !pe command, I get "no export !pe found" (this happens with any other command such as !CLRStack).

If I get the 64-bit version of mscordacwks.dll and sos.dll, and copy them into the symbol folder, the libraries will be loaded but upon running !pe command I will get `"Failed to load data access DLL, 0x80004005 error message!`

What I am doing wrong? I asked the network team to send me the .dll files (`sos.dll` and mscordacwks.dll), I copied them to the symbols folder but nothing changed.

p.s. I have read all the similar posts but none helped.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine.aspx, recapture a 32 bit dump should be your obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

Open the dump in a 32-bit debugger and run `!wow64exts.sw`.  You should now be able to load SOS and run commands, though not all commands will work.  This will help, but still the best solution is to gather the dump with a 32-bit tool.